# jQuery - accessing function within switch() from outside

Tags: jquery

At the top of my JavaScript document I have a `switch()` function which - based on the current page the user is on - declares which JS functions are to be loaded, which plugins are to be fired, etc.

Now, for my example let's say I'm on page `index`. When the user is on the index page I fire a plugin called DataTables (you might know it). I'm including a simplified version of the plugin call in my switch function.

Within the switch function I also create a function called `refreshDataTable()` - this is what this question is about - which is supposed to refresh the table.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var currentPage = ...  

switch (currentPage) {

    case 'index':

    var table = $('#table').DataTable( {
       ajax: "data.json"
       // and many more parameters
    } );

    function refreshDataTable() {
       table.ajax.reload();
    }

    break;

}

});

// try to call function here, not working
refreshDataTable();
```

So far so good, the plugin loads as expected and the `refreshDataTable()` is accessible from within the `switch()` function.

Now, the problem is that I need to call the `refreshDataTable()` function from outside of the `switch()` function. Whenever I try to do this there is an error saying the function does not exist.

Does anybody have an idea how I can access this function from outside of the `switch()` without having to fire the entire DataTables plugin again?

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE: I noticed that this is not working because the `switch()` is wrapped in a `document.ready` function. Why? And would it not be inefficient to simply remove the `document.ready` function?

Comment: That function definition is inside of document ready handler. So it cannot be accessible outside of it.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I noticed that - however, removing the document ready handler could be a performance issue, don't you think? Especially considering that within my `switch()` function I am calling quite a few plugins and functions as part of config.

Comment: Why is `refreshDataTable()` defined within the switch within the doc ready?

Comment: @j08691: Because if it was not defined within the `switch()` (or doc ready, for that matter) the `table` variable would not be accessible

Comment: So define the variables outside and use them inside. It's all about scope.

Comment: @Frank Instead of inside out why can't you try outside in access?

Comment: @j08691: But if I move the `var table = ...` outside of the doc ready or the switch it would cause the `DataTable` function to be called every time the site loads, regardless of which page. What I'm trying to do is only call it on the index page.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: I'm not entirely sure about what you mean. Could you clarify? Thx

Comment: `var table;` outside, `table = $('#table').DataTable( {` inside. And you're getting the "the function does not exist" message because you run `refreshDataTable();` before the function is defined because doc ready hasn't executed yet.

Comment: @j08691 & Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy Thank you so much guys, this worked. I can't believe I did not think of specifying the variable name outside. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write your code like this,

```
(function(){

   var table;

   function refreshDataTable() {
      if(table && table.length) {
        table.ajax.reload();
      }
   }

   $(document).ready(function(){
    var currentPage = ...  
    switch (currentPage) {
      case 'index':
        table = $('#table').DataTable( {
             ajax: "data.json"
             // and many more parameters
        });
      break;
    }
  });

  refreshDataTable();
}();
```

Comment: @Frank Glad to help! :)